# Are there any historical examples of successful price ceilings (aka price gouging laws)?

Tags: economy

Thomas Sowell writes the following in his book "Basic Economics":

> If the prices of hotel rooms remain what they have been in normal
> times, those who happen to arrive at the hotels first will take all
> the rooms, and those who arrive later will either have to sleep
> outdoors, or in damaged homes that may offer little protection from
> the weather, or else leave the local area and thus leave their homes
> vulnerable to looters. But, if hotel prices rise sharply, people will
> have incentives to ration themselves. A couple with children, who
> might rent one hotel room for themselves and another for their
> children, when the prices are kept down to their normal level, will
> have incentives to rent just one room for the whole family when the
> rents are abnormally high—that is, when there is “price gouging.”

Are there any historical examples of price ceilings (often called "price gouging" laws) that have worked well in retrospective? That is, I'm looking for historical examples of price ceilings where:

1. There wasn't a shortage of goods as a result of the law
2. A significant black market did not appear as a response to the law
3. The law was considered a success in retrospective by unbiased parties

There's plenty of examples of failed price gouging laws (such as [Zimbabwe's failed attempt](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2007/jul/05/zimbabwe.topstories3) in 2007) but are there any successful ones?

Comment: I don't know about the rest of the book but the example you quote sets up an unrealistic situation and then suggests an unealistic outcome. First, if some natural disaster destroys a lot of homes, people just indiviually looking for alternative accomodation on the free market is not what usually happens. In general the government steps in and provides emergency shelter. Second, if some unusual situation creates a surge in demand and prices everyone rationing themselves a bit is not what usually happens. Rather the ones who can afford it behave as before and the others get nothing.

Comment: Do [fixed book prices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_book_price) count? They are generally considered a success in Germany and have not led to book shortages as far as I am aware.

Comment: What about subsidied goods? E.g. it seems subsidied bread is sold [at a fixed price in Egypt](https://www.reuters.com/world/africa/egypt-sell-discounted-bread-fight-inflation-2023-01-16/). As far as I know this program is at least three decades old, so it is probably considered somewhat successful by Egyptians.

Comment: @Jan fixed book prices are a price *floor* rather than a price *ceiling*. The Egyptian bread program wouldn’t count because it’s just a form of a subsidy.

Comment: @quarague if the government quickly steps in there’s no need for price gouging laws because no one would pay for a good they can get for free from the government.

Comment: To follow up the example in the OP: rent raise restrictions in New York City are often cited as an unsuccessful example (shortage and black market of subletting). Another related issue is that in EU couples with children are often forced to rent more than one room, even if the children are too young to sleep separately - due to the fire safety regulations in hotels (e.g., two parents, a child and a baby technically make four people - too many for a room with two or three sleeping places.)

Comment: Very little of the answers & comments really seem responsive to the question. i wonder if that is because people are answering the question they _want_ this to be, or if it is because the terms are insufficiently defined. I'm genuinely confused.  "

Comment: Does salary ceilings count? I'm thinking in the NBA salary cap. There is no shortage of players, neither a parallel league (black market) or somebody (except the player maybe) complaining about the rule.

Comment: I think Economics stack would be a better fit. Sadly we don't have many economic history questions...

Comment: @Santiago that's not a government regulation, so no

Comment: @MCW judging by comments under my answers, the terms "shortage" and "considered a success" seem to be problematic. E.g. is there a shortage if you have to wait ten minutes for your taxi.

Comment: @JounceCracklePop I bet you would change your mind if you read the first 100 pages of the Basic Economics book. I know you won't, but if you did you'd change your mind.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think you need to go political or historical to find useful examples. Consider the limited supply, high demand good of Taylor Swift tickets. From what I've seen of ticket reselling, the ticket price is definitely below what COULD be asked. I suspect this is because Taylor Swift & Co. have a vested interest in keeping the concerts accessible. In addition to capping the prices (or at least not raising them when it's clear they could), they institute "rationing" - limits on tickets per person. It seems the success or failure hinges how well the rationing is enforced.

Comment: @JonathanReez ...though I suppose that doesn't take into account situations where a price cap risks making the good infeasible to produce, and it doesn't really cover a class of goods across an industry, but probably still a useful toy example for the thought experiment

Comment: @Blackhawk Taylor Swift tickets are a classic example of why price ceilings are a failure. Lots of disappointed fans and a huge black market. That being said, the scarcity is created on purpose to maximize the hype, so its a feature rather than a bug: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/30616/why-do-some-businesses-choose-scarcity-as-their-business-model-instead-of-raisin/45489#45489

Comment: @JonathanReez There would still be plenty of disappointed fans if the tickets were priced to the thousands and thousands of dollars that would be necessary to balance supply and demand. In my layman's view, Taylor Swift & Co. are motivated to ensure that at least some normies will end up at her concerts to maintain her popularity across a broad swath of financial means. I kind of wish we could try it both ways and see which group of angry pitchfork and torchers is more upset :P

Comment: @Blackhawk if the goal was to maximize fan satisfaction, TS would use a Dutch auction for (say) 25% of the tickets, then give away the rest via lottery for $5/piece, with the caveat being that you could only order 1 ticket per name, and there being mandatory ID checks at the stadium for the lottery tickets. This would keep the revenues exactly the same while destroying the black market and ensuring *true* fairness. But this is not done because it would ruin the hype.

Comment: @JonathanReez I have every confidence that Ticket Master would find a way to botch that idea as well ;)

Comment: @MCW definition of "black market" seems to be flexible as well. Does the term "black market" include international corporations that are very openly and transparently doing legal business?

Comment: The main purpose of price ceiling is to prevent price from going up from the fair price compared to production costs and other amortised research cost. The goal is to prevent artificial shortages created by manufacturers, supported by patent laws, and with profits going towards excessive executive and shareholders bonuses instead of production and R&D. The price should therefore be set to just slightly higher than what market normal market would normally end up being anyway when the market is working correctly.

Comment: The goal of price controls are meant to just bring things into fair market price rather than making it affordable. There are goods whose fair market price are never going to be affordable no matter the good intent of all the participants. Once you reached fair market price, if you want to make things actually affordable to people who can't normally afford them, you need to use subsidies instead of or in addition to price controls.

Comment: @LieRyan I think you should read the full Basic Economics book, as you misunderstand the fundamentals of how prices work.

Comment: @JonathanReez the theory of Basic Economics only works in an actually free market that's completely free from government intervention. Thing is, modern "free" markets are far from being free, especially the drug markets which is filled with market manipulations enabled by patents abuse and mutual collusion due to extremely high barrier of entry. You need more than just the basics of economics to understand markets that aren't completely free.

Comment: @LieRyan arguing for even more government intervention to solve the existing government manipulation of the market is silly. Deregulation is the way to go.

Comment: @JonathanReez Even basic economic theory predicts that price ceilings can increase overall market welfare in a monopoly.

Comment: @JonathanReez Free markets are the spherical cows of economics. If you honestly believe that such a thing exists (or could even exist), you are severely misguided. Any real-world instance of a market requires more nuanced analysis beyond the 'frictionless planes' and 'inelastic collisions' that are free markets and rational agents.

Comment: @JonathanReez Trying to maximise for fan satisfaction is actually a great example of where current markets fail, because it maps very poorly to an individual's value of currency.  There's along list of artists who lament that the front rows of their concerts are filled with bored rich people and their much younger dates.  And many have tried various ideas to fix this.  Similar situation in many sports events where to the best boxes end up going to the wealthy to use for networking.

Comment: @Chuu artists who truly care have a dozen ways of solving the problem. But most just want to virtue signal, maximize profits and create artificial scarcity.

Comment: @JonathanReez I do not disagree that artists who truly care have ways to try to solve the problem.  But it's a bit disingenuous to take those attempts and then cite people trying to work around the restrictions as an example of price caps failing.

Comment: @Chuu my point is that concert ticket price caps are an example of a why price ceilings don’t work, not the other way around.

Comment: @JounceCracklePop - No surprise, since Sowell, while a qualified economist, is well-known for being at least as devoted to being a conservative ideologue who has devoted much of his writing to defending laissez-faire economics, meaning that he does not like to consider situations that might not support his philosophical presuppositions. For instance, he implicitly presumes that hotel prices will be affordable for anyone, with the consequence being that people will need to share a room, without considering the possibility that they will be priced out of the range of those who need them most.

Comment: In some situations, sufficiently high prices will prevent some poorer people who have lost their houses from finding lodging at all, with the rooms being largely occupied by those who have the economic means to go further afield and otherwise would, or even people unaffected by the disaster. This can lead to an outcome that is suboptimal in terms of total utility, where fewer people have any lodging *overall*.

Comment: @Obie2.0 without "price gouging" the rooms will be given away on a first-come-first-serve model, without any incentive to share rooms or seek more distant accommodations. It also fails to create a strong incentive for local house owners to make some big bucks by opening up their houses to strangers temporarily. Nor does "price gouging" prevent the government from providing assistance. Sowell addresses all of these objections in the book.

Comment: @JonathanReez - The incentive to share rooms may already exist: people have lost their houses and are likely in a financially unstable situation. To be frank, Sowell's notion of people who have lost their houses renting more rooms than necessary is something that only people who are already privileged could permit themselves. In many situations, local homeowners will not be able to make much money, because their houses would be damaged, or because impoverished disaster refugees could not afford their rates, or because they just cannot easily advertise in the aftermath of a disaster.

Comment: Government subsidies, which I assume you would have to mean by "assistance," is all well and good for getting people money after the fact, but it is not going to get someone a room if they have been completely priced out of it. Sowell just does not seem to recognize the existence of situations in which high prices can prevent those who most need a product (high marginal utility) from getting it, while allowing those who least need it (low marginal utility) to acquire it.

Comment: But, see, the difference between me and an ideologue is that I accept that there probably are situations where Sowell's concerns dominate, depending on things like the average income of those affected by disasters and the supply and distribution of housing, among other factors. Does *he* accept that there are situations were his prescriptions would be counterproductive? I rather doubt it.

Comment: @Obie2.0 again - the alternatives to “price gouging” are rationing or first come first serve. Both often result in a black market or at least in a misallocation of resources, while failing to induce entrepreneurs to bring in more supply to the market. This was very much obvious during the pandemic when people working from home hoarded boxes of masks while hospitals couldn’t obtain any - if price gouging was allowed, masks would go up 10x in price as early as January 2020 and we’d have plenty of new supply by March. Ditto for toilet paper.

Comment: @JonathanReez except when they don't as seen with EU pharmaceuticals. No relevant black market (beyond that seen in underregulated countries as well for recreational use), no shortages beyond disasters mirrored in underregulated countries. Also: Factories don't spawn overnight just because your magical market wills it so

Comment: @quarague - The government stepping in to provide housing to people whose homes have been damaged or who are fleeing a disaster is something that **never** happens in the U.S. in the days leading up to or after a natural disaster.  The fastest response ever has been on the order of a week, and a month is more typical.  Professor Sowell's scenario is 100% reasonable in his home country.

Comment: @MCW - Few people are really addressing the question because **the answer** (there is no historical example where anti-gouging price controls did work, according to the OP's -- very nice, IMHO -- definition of "worked") **makes people very uncomfortable.**  Professor Sowell often has that effect on people.  So people say something else, instead.

Comment: First the earth cooled. And then the dinosaurs came, but they got too big and fat, so they all died and they turned into oil. **And then Ronald Reagan repealed the predatory lending laws** that were enacted after The Great Depression, and CC companies started charging 30%. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savings_and_loan_crisis ... Savings... and Loan *Shark* Crisis.

Comment: "The Federal Reserve's efforts to reduce rampant inflation of the late 1970s and early 1980s by **raising interest rates brought on a recession** in the early 1980s and the beginning of the S&L crisis." - For *price gouging*, google OPEC : "The group can achieve this **by coordinating** supply cuts when the price is deemed too low and supply increases **when its members *believe*** prices are too high." -that's the definition of *price gouging*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WW2 had price controls in the US and UK, combined with rationing, and these held up fairly well:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_Price_Administration
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationing_in_the_United_Kingdom

It's arguable that rationing (or shortages) is required along with price controls. Shortage can be viewed as another form of inflation (for instance before the recent rise in inflation, there were shortages in goods and services - construction being one affected area - in many countries).

Comment: You forget (or ignore) the huge black market around rationing.

Comment: "fairly well" - not perfectly.

Comment: @Jos yes it was there but even with the black market it was massively better than the alternative

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's the only one that answers the spirit of my question.

Answer (score 20):

In Czech Republic (and AFAIK most of Europe), almost all medical drugs have had tightly controlled prices for the last couple decades. This price control in some senses does and in others does not fit your requirements:

1. Shortages. Among the thousands of regulated items, at any given time there is almost always a shortage of a handful of items. On the other hand, you could almost certainly find many drugs that never experienced a shortage. Also the causal relation between the price control and shortages is difficult to establish as Czechia is a small market and most of the shortages (e.g. due to one of only two plants for the drug in the whole world closing down) affect the whole European region or the whole world.
2. Black market. Similarly, at any given point there are quite likely some drugs that have black markets. This AFAIK most typically mean pharmacies illegaly re-exporting drugs to sell at higher prices. Actual consuments/patients buying medicine on black markets is AFAIK very rare. Many other drugs are not affected.
3. The experience for most of the population is that you almost always can obtain drugs you need at OK-ish prices (many 100% covered by health insurance). There are IMHO very few countries where the patient experience is better and the contrast is especially stark with the US. But hey this is biased towards the interests of patients, I'd bet pharma companies are not so thrilled, so not sure if that counts :-D

So if you focused narrowly enough on some specific set of drugs, you could almost certainly find those that satisfy your requirements. The system as a whole experiences some problems and pressures and is definitely not perfect, but I have yet to see a better solution.

There are also concerns that the price controls may disincentivise innovation. I don't think this has been very clearly established (the system is willing to pay huge money for some therapies) and anyway, as long as US patients are OK with footing the bill for a lot of pharma research, I don't see why we in less prosperous countries shouldn't accept their generous offer.

Comment: Does this refer to prescription drugs or over-the-counter drugs? For prescription drugs, isn't supply tightly controlled by doctors issuing prescriptions? So it's not like you can just go ahead and hoard a 5 year supply of diabetes medicine.

Comment: I think you're acknowledging at the end that price controls at least distort the market such that customers in areas not subject to ceilings partially subsidize the costs of customers in markets with ceilings.  I guess that can be viewed as success from the perspective of people benefiting from such subsidies, and that isn't one of the specific ill effects called out in the question, but I wouldn't characterize it as "working well" in a global sense.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, demand for medicines is limited due to prescriptions, but that is not different from countries that do not have such price caps? And you can also not realistically hoard a five-year supply of bread or fresh vegetables.

Comment: @Jan hoarding is just one side of the problem. The other problem is that producers will inevitably give up and leave the market if they can no longer make a  profit at the capped price. Hoarding is often the last stage of a price ceiling disaster.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am just trying to find out how exactly your first comment is relevant to price caps on medicine. When it basically describes stuff that is equally valid in systems without a price cap

Comment: @Martin Modrák I think the answer could be improved by specifying whether you are talking about over-the-counter prices (what patients pay in a pharmacy) or about wholesale prices (what pharma companies get when selling their drugs). E.g. Germany *regulates* wholesale prices and *subsidizes* over-the-counter prices. OP has stated somewhere that subsidies are out of scope for this question.

Comment: "So if you focused narrowly enough on ...." True, but that works the other way around too.

Comment: @JonathanReez You write that a sign of failure is that "producers will inevitably give up and leave the market". This very clearly has not happened on any non-trivial scale so the measures are successful in that sense.

Comment: Sadly, as far as I am aware, some pharmaceutical products are actually currently seeing or were seeing a shortage, at least in Germany, in part because of supply chain disruptions during Corona crisis, but also because of too tight price ceilings which makes it unprofitable to produce them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you restrict yourself to any economic policy which works well "in a global sense" you would find examples very few and far between.

Comment: Perhaps not, @DanSheppard, but that's kinda the point.  If you apply pressure to tip the scales then you can be pretty confident that that's going to have side effects that tend to balance it out.  You, as policy maker, may be ok with that, but you should not pretend it isn't happening or that you couldn't have anticipated it.

Comment: @JonathanReez quick notes from a French point of view : here, any medication, OTC or not, has its price determined when it gets authorized for public sale. The government then decides how much is reimbursed by our social security system ([gov source in french](https://sante.gouv.fr/soins-et-maladies/medicaments/le-circuit-du-medicament/article/la-fixation-des-prix-et-du-taux-de-remboursement)).

Comment: @JonathanReez (cont.) Regarding the profits, if you take the example of Sanofi (biggest French pharma lab), it makes 23% of its profits in Europe, 43% in the US. While the US market is more profitable, they still keep most of their R&D in Europe

Comment: Also (German perspective but pretty much the same thing): Those medication shortcomings that do exist have real-world crises causing them (like cough medicine in 2022) and could also be observed in underregulated countries

Answer (score 13):

Taxi prices in Germany are set by [local governments](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxitarif), and I think consensus is that this has been successful so far.

---

Prices for some other services (such as lawyers and architects) are also regulated, though the most well-known and most strict regulation is the [price regulation for medical services](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geb%C3%BChrenordnung_f%C3%BCr_%C3%84rzte).

This particular regulation has existed for about 125 years, so we may conclude that it has been considered successful. I am also not aware of any black market or shortages - quite the opposite: if you offer to pay according to said price regulation (as opposed to letting social insurance handle the payment), doctors are supposedly quite happy and quick to offer you an appointment.

Comment: While I am skeptical of the conclusion, I think you're on to a very profitable line of inquiry. Well. don.

Comment: Did Germany not suffer from a shortage of taxis before Uber came around to the market? That was the case for every country with fixed taxi prices as of 2010, as far as I know. As for doctors - how do the wait times for seeing a doctor in Germany compare to wait times in the US which has no such price caps?

Comment: @JonathanReez 1st question: No, *as far as I know*. But seriously I have never had a problem with finding a taxi in Germany. I noted serious problems in France last year though, *despite* Uber. 2. question: no idea, but probably not so much that every *unbiased party* would describe it as a shortage (note my explicit caveat re. social insurance however).

Comment: @Jan are there any charts for the median taxi wait times in major cities pre and post Uber? In NYC I can get one in ~60 seconds right now which was unbelievably fast pre-Uber, unless you got lucky and hailed one quickly on the street.

Comment: @JonathanReez how would that be relevant to your question? I see something about "black market" and "shortage", and nothing about average waiting times.

Comment: @JonathanReez Also note that this improvement in waiting times seems dependent on mobile internet or at least mobile phone communication. Germany's regulated taxi prices did work well for decades before that.

Comment: For both taxis and lawyers, I'd be interested in a comparison of areas with strong regulation vs areas without such regulations. Did the fixed price on lawyers not have an impact on wait times, for example?

Comment: nit: in many locations **Uber** (and similar services) are considered (part of) the "black market", because they're operating outside the otherwise regulated taxi industry.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse excellent point! The very existence of Uber shows why the price ceilings were a failure.

Comment: This also a good testing ground for hypothesis. Because both Finland and Sweden used to have the same system. But they have been dismantled since then. And it is generally accepted that the entire dismantling was a total clusterf**k. Although the system has stabilized to a WORSE system. So yes theres a bit more availability of taxis during peak hours. But off hours not so much and the prices did not go down they went up initially by quite much. And quite many people have stopped using taxis because of the system confusion.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think your conclusion makes any sense regarding Uber proofing any point. Not paying legally required employee benefits by being in a legally gray/black area gave Uber a big advantage . Add to that the situations where - once you account for car depreciation etc. - Uber drivers ended up earning less than minimum wage per hour worked (literally happened to a friend of a good friend) and I think there are very few lessons about price ceilings to be learned here.

Comment: @DavidMulder yes it shows that price floors (aka minimum wage) should not exist either

Comment: @JonathanReez Your question was interesting, but your interactions with people in the comments make it feel like this question was completely made in bad faith. The average person's inability to correctly estimate the cost of running a business and getting tricked by advertising promising incredible profits is absolutely in no way proof that minimum wages shouldn't exist. Reminder: Minimum wages are about human decency, trying to force the market to not maximize for profits completely (or put differently, it sets the bounds within which we want to optimize).

Comment: @DavidMulder currently only 2% of Americans work for minimum wage, proving that the lower boundary is not at all necessary in a free market. Natural competition between employers is more than sufficient.

Comment: @JonathanReez - federal minimum wage?  Many states/cities set their own minimums as well, especially where the cost of living may be higher.  In many cases, though, the minimum wage is still a poverty wage.

Answer (score 10):

In recent history, Canada introduced and enforced a price ceiling of $0 for the various COVID-19 vaccines as they became available.  It was not legal to charge more than $0 for the vaccine, and it was not legal to purchase the vaccine for more than $0.

As far as I can recall, there were not widespread shortages of this good in Canada.  There may have been in other parts of the world, but I'm not sure how much of that can be blamed on the Canadian price ceiling.

As far as I know, there wasn't a significant black market.

Was it considered successful?  Maybe.  I'm not sure if enough time has passed for anyone to be an unbiased party yet.

Quasi-relatedly, a similar $0 price ceiling was introduced (at least in Alberta, a part of Canada) for home COVID tests.  I think there may have been the occasional transient shortage with those, and at least some nascent attempt to set up an illicit market, but it all seemed pretty subdued.

Comment: The vaccine is a unique good because it can only be consumed once or twice in a lifetime (the booster was a separate vaccine). Still, there were issues such as https://news.yahoo.com/white-millionaire-canadian-couple-took-132240017.html. I’m not fully sure about Canada but in the US it resulted in inefficient allocation of the vaccine where groups such as teachers were prioritized because their union had political power.

Comment: I think you are confusing "price ceilings" and universal healthcare....

Comment: I'm guessing in this example, the Canadian government or private insurance were the ones picking up the tab. If that's the case, vaccine producers and vendors did not receive $0 per dose. This is not an example of a price ceiling, but a price subsidy.

Comment: @JonathanReez I agree that vaccines have an usually-abrupt marginal utility function -- my hunch is that generally they'd be worth considering, as you continue your search through the annals of history.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus I agree that it's subsidized, but I don't think it makes a difference for our purposes.  Consider that example from the question -- nothing changes if there's a consumer price cap of $20 with government subsidies picking up the rest of the hotel room cost.

Comment: it is not just a subsidy example, but a closed market with no competition. No one else besides a few companies had vaxxes approved by the government. Moreover, end users were forced to take the product. It is hard to think about an example farther away from a free market.

Comment: @Roger It would make a difference though. A real price ceiling scenario would likely result in the development of a black market for hotel rooms, where hotel owners would reject customers unwilling to pay a price above the imposed limit, in favor of those willing to pay it under the table. In your price subsidy scenario, this black market is unlikely to arise because the hotel owner is getting their asking price from the government. Price ceilings vs. price subsidies are two completely different things with two completely different end results, even in the hotel room example.

Comment: @JonathanReez soooo we have a perfectly valid example and you just go "nu uh that doesn't count"? Have you maybe considered your ideology to simply not line up with reality?

Comment: @JonathanReez "groups such as teachers were prioritized because their union had political power" Right, it had nothing to do with the fact that they have to spend hours every workday with a bunch of snot-nosed kids.

Comment: @JimmyJames the teachers unions dragged their feet on reopening [despite getting vaccinated early](https://www.foxnews.com/us/oakland-teachers-refuse-to-return-to-school-despite-getting-covid-vaccine-priority). And they took away vaccine slots from the elderly who are 10-100x more at risk than the median teacher.

Comment: @JonathanReez Elderly people are not required to be around dozens of germy kids on a daily basis.

Comment: @JimmyJames yeah and neither were California teachers as schools were mostly remote as of January 2021 ;) Then they got the vaccine and still delayed the reopening for... reasons.

Answer (score 5):

[EU price caps on natural gas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU_natural_gas_price_cap) seem to work reasonably well so far.

Comment: This directly [contradicts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79757/7434) the answer on a related Politics.SE question.

Comment: Can you elaborate where exactly you see a contradiction? Are you implying there is no price cap? Or is it maybe something else?

Comment: Or are you saying that the EU gas price caps do not work because whatever the UK did did not work? My answer was specifically about the EU-level price cap, which (I think) is unrelated to the UK.

Comment: The contradiction is that many EU countries *did* let prices increase and those with the largest prices saw the largest reduction in consumption (which makes perfect sense). So I wouldn't call it a success.

Comment: @JonathanReez it seems you are moving the goalposts here. Price ceilings does not mean that prices are fixed, or at least that is not what you wrote in your question. Also my answer is about the EU-level price cap introduced in December 2022, not about individual countries.

Comment: @Jan the contradiction is that he's only here for self-validation (at best) or trolling (at worst). He's not interested in any actual counterexamples and dismisses any he can't "argue" against.

Comment: @Hobbamok incorrect, after reading the story of rationing in the UK during WWII I'm now convinced it was a success and that letting prices free float would not have been better. But this doesn't mean that the other answers are actually good.

Comment: @JonathanReez (any) wartime rationing are  prime examples of an answer that violates point 2 of your questions. I'm glad you came around but maybe it's not the answers that aren't good but how you phrased your question(s). Which is also why I assumed you bad intentions, sorry for that part of my comments

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly historical since it is still in effect, but compulsory licenses for music in the US functionally caps the royalties for sheet music at $0.08 (there is a long list of caveats to that; for example it only applies to songs under 5 minutes in length and doesn't apply if you record video of your performance). You are free to negotiate a lower price with the rights holder of course, and this does happen, but since you always have the option of the $0.08 license there isn't much a rights holder can do to convince you to pay more.

This has definitely not lead to any shortages or black markets, since you can't really have a shortage of intellectual property. The cost of producing an additional copy is always $0.

I think this is pretty clearly a price cap, though I don't think I would call this a price gouging law. In general I think it is interesting to apply economic principals to intellectual property since the supply curve is **so** different from what I learned about in basic economics classes.

Comment: Your assertion that creators will create even when not compensated is suspect. Can you provide evidence that the number of creative artists does not decline as they starve?

Comment: @MCW I didn't mean to make that assertion. Perhaps you refer to my assertion that you can create additional copies of existing intellectual property for $0? I only ment to say that we can't experience a shortage of the song "Bohemian Rhapsody" for example. The first copy is expensive to make. Subsequent copies are free.

Comment: "you can't really have a shortage of intellectual property".  Effectively the assertion is that intellectual property is a unique type of property that will be produced no matter     The example you cite in your comment is  illustrates a  _quite_ different principle.  NOTE with emphasis; You've raised some very  interesting implications, but  I'm now guilty of discussion in comments. I invite you to have the last word. (pity, it would be an interesting discussion in an economics stack exchange. )